# How to add new object to the array of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

I have two classes, namely `Players`  and `Team`   In the `Team`  class, I have array of  `Players` instances, and the `MAX_SİZE = 11`

```
#define MAX 11
class Players{
// Some private and public members 
};
class Team {
private:
    Players players[MAX];
// Some other private and public members
};
```

I want to implement the `addNewPlayer` method in my `Team`  class.
Whenever I call this method, I should be able to the add the name of the player to the end of this `Players` instances array, which is `players`. Now the function I consider is like :

```
void Team :: addNewPlayer(Players new_player){
       // add new_player to the end of the array
       }
```

I know the `Stacks` and `Queues` data structures as well. However, there is a restriction on using arrays only.

Is there any efficient way of adding new object to the array of objects in other class in general?

Comment: `players[currentNumberOfPlayers] = new_player`?

Comment: `Players players[MAX];` You can't change the size of that - it's fixed at `MAX`.

Comment: In C++, arrays don't have a concept of "add to the end".  If an array holds 11 Players, that size cannot change.  It will always and only hold 11 Players.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp. Yes the size is fixed by 11, which is an upper bound. I can add at most 11 players to the team. What is wrong with this if the team is initally empty?

Comment: Don't.  Replace array with `std::vector` and use `std::vector::push_back()`.

Comment: `Players players[MAX];` creates an array with 11 `Player` objects. You can't "add" but you can assign a new player to one of the existing items as mentioned in the 1st comment. You might want to create an `operator=` for the `Players` class.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for "placement `new`". That allows you to construct an object at a specific address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`players` **array** is defined within **Team** *class*. To assign it a *size*; you use the variable `MAX`, *if* this variable uses an appropriate *value*, suppose one different from its maximum capacity that depends on the *hardware*, you can try creating a new array replacing the one of the class with a new length and element:

```
void Team::addNewPlayer(Players new_player) {

    // add new_player to the end of the array
    int newSize = sizeof(players)/sizeof(players[0]);
    Players newArray[newSize+1];
    
    for (int i=0; i < newSize; i++) {
        newArray[i] = players[i];
    }

    newArray[newSize] = new_player;
    players = newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the current count of players in your team. Then you'll want to add a new_player to the players[currentcount]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).